# Spring Security login problem after migration spring boot 1.5 -> 2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servletcontextlistener

I need a help
I'm doing migration spring boot 1.5.17 -> 2.2.1 and everything is fine except spring security.
The problem is I can't login from my login form(tried default login page, same result). Login with basic auth works fine. 
I have enabled debug logs with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG  config but still nothing.
What I noticed is when I'm typing wrong credentials - it says 'Username/password is incorrect' so seems the problem is not with password encoder, as spring security version changed.
Than I check browser's networks devtool tab and I can see following: first request goes to /login -> than it redirects to /welcome and than again to /login  [(see on screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woHS2.png)
Here is my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

           http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/script/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true)
                .failureUrl("/login/error").permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
    }   

}
```

Help please

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check the [Security related chapter of the migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#security)?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Thank you for advise, checked that, not helped

Comment: Trying adding `.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()`

Comment: Hi @Rajeev, Tried, doesn't help

Comment: It might be helpful if you could reduce the code you are sharing down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue. Also, in my effort to look for odd things in your configuration, it seems strange that you are both publishing an AuthenticationSuccessHandler as a Bean and specifying a default success url.

Comment: Hi @jzheaux, thank you for advise, removed all redundant code. Removed SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler bean as well, doesn't help.

Comment: If you remove httpBasic, does it still happen? What about the various ant matchers? I'd recommend removing anything from the configuration that doesn't contribute to the behavior.

Comment: @jzheaux, updated configuration, removed httpBasic, removed all antmachers as welcome page requires only to be authenticated, but still the same

Comment: Hi gays, thank you all for comments, I found reason why it happened and it is not Spring Security config. The problem was in servetContext config. I had it like 
public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) {
  sc.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
  sc.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);
 }, changed setSecure to false and woks now.